# Effects of taking too much painkillers

Tags: side-effects, analgesics, acetaminophen

What side effect or health damages will occur if a person takes too much pain killer medicine?

Comment: Welcome to health stack exchange:-) What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is what side effect or health damages will occur if I take too much pain killer medicine?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). You should include the actual question (what are the possible side effects of too much pain killers) and also add details about what sort of medicine it is and what you consider to be "too much", so that we could answer your question. Personal medical advice is strictly off-topic for this site so you should edit out personal medical history. Otherwise your question looks like you are asking for diagnosis and it will probably be closed as off-topic. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucky thank you for informing me. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, taking too much painkiller can be harmful. Two common painkillers are acetaminophen (brand name Tylenol) and ibuprofen (brand name Advil). They each have different risks.

#### Paracetamol / Acetaminophen

The [maximum daily dose](https://www.healthline.com/health/acetaminophen-overdose) is 3,000 mg. With the 650 mg extended release pills, the daily limit is just 4 pills. Never consume more than 4,000 mg in a 24 hour period. Passing either of these limits may result in liver damage and/or death.

> Between 2001 and 2010, more than 1,500 people in the U.S. died from accidental acetaminophen overdoses. [Source](https://www.huffingtonpost.ca/entry/tylenol-overdose_n_3976991)

*The amounts specified are for a fully-grown adult; the maximum dose for children is lower. Consult with a pediatrician for advice on giving painkillers to children.*

#### Ibuprofen

The maximum daily dose of Ibuprofen is 2,400 mg. Most pills are 200 mg each, so the daily limit is 12 pills. Exceeding this limit is likely to cause the development of stomach ulcers (a break in the mucous membrane that fails to heal).

*The amounts specified are for a fully-grown adult; the maximum dose for children is lower. Consult with a pediatrician for advice on giving painkillers to children.*

Comment: For those wondering what acetaminophen is, it‘s called paracetamol in other regions of the world.

Comment: Your link to the max dose of 3g daily of paracetamol doesn't say that.  So, where did you source that from?  Consider also that we routinely prescribe 4g daily.

Comment: @GrahamChiu from my link, "McNeil Consumer Healthcare (the maker of Tylenol) lowered their recommended maximum daily dose to 3,000 mg. Many pharmacists and healthcare providers agree with this recommendation."

Comment: Ahh, your link is to a particular part of that page which doesn't mention doses.  Anyway, it's a confusing answer as it's more nuanced that to just give a single figure.  I think we should just close the question which is off topic anyway

Comment: @GrahamChiu Off topic because the question pertains to an individual, or off topic because the question isn't about medications used to treat diseases?

Comment: Because of all the personal details which doesn't seem to contain a question except in the comments.

Comment: You covered two pain meds. There are at least 8 entire classes of pain medications and dozens of individual drugs.

Comment: @CareyGregory Sounds like you know enough to write a great answer!